# Add Button Tag Buttons inside SearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, tags, uitextfield, textfield

I want to implement when I start editing inside search bar, then list would appear below the searchbar and I would select multiple values from list and when I want to select any text  It would be add inside my search bar or textfield like button like this image below

[image]

this is example from stack overflow, so please guide me how to implement this I have no idea about this implementation, you can refer also third party library also and if you can help me with code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*may it will works*
i suggested to use textfield as search engine

write code inside add button

let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.setTitle("name", for: UIControlState.normal)
button.frame = CGRect((x: CGFloat(txt.frame.size.width - 25), y: CGFloat(5), width: CGFloat(25), height: CGFloat(25)))

button.addTarget(self,action: #selector(action), for: .touchUpInside)

textField.rightView = button

textField.rightViewMode = .always

*use array to save the values*

Comment: it's display in right view, I want multiple buttons inside textfield not in right viwe

Comment: when click  add ,buttons  will added inside textfield itself only, and make it leftViewMode!

Comment: what if I want to add multiple buttons inside this, would it work?

Comment: yes..when click add button refresh array of count with values .change x position inside textfield when you add every  value(button)

Comment: i was worked these type pattern on UIview, i hope it can works on this